# Validar varios input con una sola funcion

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un formulario hecho en HTML con varios controles y un script en javascript para validar si estan llenos o no, el problema es que quiero validar cada uno pero no hacer una funcion para cada control

```js
window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementById('placa').onblur = Validar;
 document.getElementById('modelo').onblur = Validar;
 document.getElementById('municipio').onblur = Validar;
 //funcion para que le de el foco no mas se pase el mouse
 document.getElementById('placa').onmouseover = Foco;
 document.getElementById('modelo').onmouseover = Foco;
 document.getElementById('municipio').onmouseover = Foco;
 
}
function Foco(){
 var placa = document.getElementById('placa');
 placa.focus();

}
function Validar(){ 
 var placa = document.getElementById('placa');
 placa.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  this.setCustomValidity('');
 });
 placa.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
 // Required
  if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
   this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digitar la placa');
   this.focus();
  }
 });
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/plantilla_gral.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/marcas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
   <h2>Registrar nueva moto</h2>
   <div class ="contenedor-input">
    <input type = "text" id = "placa" name = "placa" placeholder = "Ingresar placa" class = "input-100" required />
    <select name="marca" id="marca" class="input-100"></select>
    <select name="linea" id="linea" class="input-100"></select>
    <input type = "text" id = "modelo" name = "modelo" placeholder = "Ingrese modelo moto" class = "input-48"/>
    <select name="color" id="color" class="input-48"></select>
    <input type = "text" id = "municipio" name = "municipio" placeholder = "Municipio de la matricula" class = "input-100"/>
    <select name = "estado id = "estado" class = "input-100">
    <option value = 0> Escoga un estado del RUNT</option>
    <option value = "Activo">Activo</option>
    <option value = "Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
    <option value = "No registra">No registra</option>
    <input type = "date" id = "soat" name = "soat" class = "input-48" alt="Ingresar fecha vencimiento del SOAT" />
    <input type = "date" id = "tecno" name = "tecno" class = "input-48"/>
    <input type="submit" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar"/>
   </div>  
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como pueden ver el código la función validar es la que se encarga de corroborar si están llenos o no los input, trate de hacerlo con un switch, pero me doy cuenta que al cargar la ventana mandaría el parámetro a la función, pero siempre quedaría con la ultimo opción, como hago esto de manera que en cualquier momento me lo valide.

Comment: Solo el input `placa` es `required`.  Si agregas `required` a los demas inputs, tu codigo funciona.

Comment: Si funciona, pero me tocaría crear una función por cada input para crear el error personalizado y lo que quiero es con una sola función poderlos validar todos

Comment: Puedes usar esta libreria para validar de forma mas sencilla tus formularios: https://github.com/dvdeveloper/PHP-Class-Validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas una funcion, puedes hacerlo todo en el `onload`.  Ademas la funcionalidad del `focus` no es muy amigable para el usuario.  Yo lo haria asi:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
   inputs[i].addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
   });
   inputs[i].addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
 // Required
    if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
     this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digitar el valor');
     this.focus();
    }
   });
  }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/plantilla_gral.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/marcas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
   <h2>Registrar nueva moto</h2>
   <div class ="contenedor-input">
    <input type = "text" id = "placa" name = "placa" placeholder = "Ingresar placa" class = "input-100" required />
    <select name="marca" id="marca" class="input-100"></select>
    <select name="linea" id="linea" class="input-100"></select>
    <input type = "text" id = "modelo" name = "modelo" placeholder = "Ingrese modelo moto" class = "input-48"/ required>
    <select name="color" id="color" class="input-48"></select>
    <input type = "text" id = "municipio" name = "municipio" placeholder = "Municipio de la matricula" class = "input-100"/ required>
    <select name = "estado id = "estado" class = "input-100">
    <option value = 0> Escoga un estado del RUNT</option>
    <option value = "Activo">Activo</option>
    <option value = "Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
    <option value = "No registra">No registra</option>
    <input type = "date" id = "soat" name = "soat" class = "input-48" alt="Ingresar fecha vencimiento del SOAT" />
    <input type = "date" id = "tecno" name = "tecno" class = "input-48"/>
    <input type="submit" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar"/>
   </div>  
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola espero ser de ayuda.

Primero los inpu y select lo colocaria dentro de un formulario y cada ves que el formulario cambia se valida.

A una cosa si quieres que no sena basicio solo con colocarle requido al input lo valida sin nesesidad de jquery o otra validacion

```
<input type="text" name="fname" required>
```

te dejo un ejemplo

https://codepen.io/DerLeguan/pen/jpXMgP?editors=1000

saludos